# Azure DevOps pipline run descriptions

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have an ADO YAML pipeline which runs based on variables and parameters selected at the time of the run.

Is there a way to put a parameter selected into the desription / name of the run to make it obvious which selection was chosen at the time of the run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can set build number using this command

```
steps:
  - script: echo "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(CustomValue)"
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#updatebuildnumber-override-the-automatically-generated-build-number) is documentation for this.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much.  I couldn't find this in the YAML schema, do you know where it's documented?

Comment: Yeah. I added this to reply.

Comment: I ended up with add a mysterious `'` at the end - solved by turning off bash script debugging before the echo statement (`set -x`)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `name` element in your YAML:

```
parameters: 
- name: ProjectName
  type: string
    default: Default

name: "${{ parameters.ProjectName }}-Build-$(CustomValue)"

steps:
  - # build your project here
  ...
```

More details on this are at [learn.microsoft.com - Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: For the sake of completeness - `appendCommitMessageToRunName: false` is also useful if you would prefer to suppress the last-commit message of the pipeline repo - ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#pipeline-stages